# Issue inserting records from Staging table to Main Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have created a stored procedure that accepts 7 parameters and inserts the values into a StagingTable (5 records) it then checks if the data in StagingTable exists in FinalTable. If it doesn't exists insert the values into the FinalTable. However, When I run the procedure all 5 records are inserted in the Staging table but only 1 record is inserted into the FinalTable. I'm new in writing code in sql so I'm not sure where is my mistake.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertBCCData_toStaging] 
(-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@JobNo varchar(50), 
@Zip varchar(50),
@Country varchar(50),
@Copies varchar(50),
@AWB varchar(50),
@DelvCode varchar(50),
@OPSCode varchar(50) 
)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ------tranfer the BCC values in tblImportBCCDataStaging Table
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblImportBCCDataStaging (JobNo, Zip, Country, Copies, AWB, DelvCode, OPSCode)
    VALUES (@JobNo, @Zip, @Country,@Copies,@AWB,@DelvCode, @OPSCode);

    ------tranfer the Staging records in tblImportBCCData Table
    INSERT INTO dbo.tblImportBCCData (JobNo, Zip, Country, Copies, AWB, DelvCode, OPSCode)
    SELECT JobNo, Zip, Country, Copies, AWB, DelvCode, OPSCode
    FROM dbo.tblImportBCCDataStaging t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT JobNo FROM dbo.tblImportBCCData WHERE JobNo=T.JobNo);


END
```

Comment: By calling the above procedure you can insert only one record into `tblImportBCCDataStaging` staging table

Comment: The procedure inserts all 5 records into tblImportBCCDataStaging successfully, however when I insert from tblImportBCCDataStaging to tblImportBCCData only inserts 1 record.

Comment: May be for all the five records the `JobNo` is same thats why only one record is getting inserted into `tblImportBCCData`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Thanks marc_s for the input

Comment: Prdp: All the records do have the same JobNo. How can I fix the code above so that it inserts them all even do it has the same JobNo?

Answer (score 0):

As asked in the comments: *All the records do have the same JobNo. How can I fix the code above so that it inserts them all even do it has the same JobNo?* Consider checking against the non-JobNo fields in the `WHERE` clause subquery:

```
...
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT JobNo FROM dbo.tblImportBCCData sub 
                 WHERE sub.Zip = t.Zip
                   AND sub.Country = t.Country
                   AND sub.Copies = t.Copies
                   AND sub.AWB = t.AWB
                   AND sub.DelvCode = t.DelvCode
                   AND sub.OPSCode = t.OPSCode);
```

However, consider finding a more unique field than `JobNo`, shared among staging and final tables, to check against existing records instead of all fields.